# Excel 2003 Macro runtime error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: macros, microsoft-excel-2003

We are using a macro to remove rows of data from our excel 'database' that have been tagged as being completed/done. this is the coding ...

```
Private Sub cmdRemove_Click()
    Dim varResult As VbMsgBoxResult
    varResult = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to remove all completed tasks? Ensure that the database has been backed up before running this operation.", vbYesNo)
    If varResult = vbYes Then
        Database.RemoveCompletedRequests
    End If
    MsgBox "Operation completed.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

the other part of this code that is referenced:...

```
Public Sub RemoveCompletedRequests()
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim varRequests() As Request
    varRequests = GetAllRequests

    For i = LBound(varRequests) To UBound(varRequests)
        If varRequests(i).Type = eDrafting Or varRequests(i).Type = eProject Then
            Dim varTasks() As Task
            Dim blnDelete As Boolean
            blnDelete = True
            varTasks = GetAllTasksByRequestNumber(varRequests(i).RequestNumber)
            For j = LBound(varTasks) To UBound(varTasks)
                If HasCompletedStatus(varTasks(j)) = False Then
                    blnDelete = False
                End If
            Next j
            If blnDelete Then
                For j = LBound(varTasks) To UBound(varTasks)
                    DeleteTask varTasks(j)
                Next j
                DeleteRequest varRequests(i)
            End If
        Else
            Dim varTask As Task
            varTask = GetPrimaryTaskByRequestNumber(varRequests(i).RequestNumber)
            If HasCompletedStatus(varTask) Then
                DeleteTask varTask
                DeleteRequest varRequests(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

vb indicates that the macro is getting hung up on the row: database.removecompletedrequests in the first section of code I provided above.

What do I need to do to resolve this?

Database module exists with "RemoveCompletedRequests" function ... coding for this is ...

```
Public Sub RemoveCompletedRequests()
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim varRequests() As Request
varRequests = GetAllRequests

For i = LBound(varRequests) To UBound(varRequests)
    If varRequests(i).Type = eDrafting Or varRequests(i).Type = eProject Then
        Dim varTasks() As Task
        Dim blnDelete As Boolean
        blnDelete = True
        varTasks = GetAllTasksByRequestNumber(varRequests(i).RequestNumber)
        For j = LBound(varTasks) To UBound(varTasks)
            If HasCompletedStatus(varTasks(j)) = False Then
                blnDelete = False
            End If
        Next j
        If blnDelete Then
            For j = LBound(varTasks) To UBound(varTasks)
                DeleteTask varTasks(j)
            Next j
            DeleteRequest varRequests(i)
        End If
    Else
        Dim varTask As Task
        varTask = GetPrimaryTaskByRequestNumber(varRequests(i).RequestNumber)
        If HasCompletedStatus(varTask) Then
            DeleteTask varTask
            DeleteRequest varRequests(i)
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteRequestRow(pintRow As Integer)
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets.Item(mstrRequestsTable)
intRow = pintRow

While ws.Cells(intRow + 1, 1) <> ""
    ShiftRow mstrRequestsTable, intRow + 1, intRow, mintColumnsInRequestsTable
    intRow = intRow + 1
Wend
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteRequest(pvarRequest As Request)
    DeleteRequestRow FindRequestRowByRequestNumber(pvarRequest.RequestNumber)
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteTaskRow(pintRow As Integer)
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets.Item(mstrTasksTable)
intRow = pintRow

While ws.Cells(intRow + 1, 1) <> ""
    ShiftRow mstrTasksTable, intRow + 1, intRow, mintColumnsInTasksTable
    intRow = intRow + 1
Wend
End Sub

' Deletes the task as well as removing all merge links to this task.
Private Sub DeleteTask(pvarTask As Task)
    ClearMergesForReferenceNumber pvarTask.ReferenceNumber
    DeleteTaskRow FindTaskRowByReferenceNumber(pvarTask.ReferenceNumber)
End Sub

' Shifts a row of data to a different row, clearing the old row
Private Sub ShiftRow(pstrTable As String, pintSourceRow As Integer, pintTargetRow As Integer, pintNumberOfColumns As Integer)
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets.Item(pstrTable)

If pintSourceRow <> pintTargetRow Then
    For i = 1 To pintNumberOfColumns
        ws.Cells(pintTargetRow, i) = ws.Cells(pintSourceRow, i)
        ws.Cells(pintSourceRow, i) = ""
    Next i
End If
End Sub

Private Sub ClearMergesForReferenceNumber(pstrReferenceNumber As String)
Dim i As Integer
Dim varTasks() As Task
varTasks = GetAllTasks

For i = LBound(varTasks) To UBound(varTasks)
    If varTasks(i).MergedWithReferenceNumber = pstrReferenceNumber Then
        varTasks(i).MergedWithReferenceNumber = ""
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Kindly make sure a module with name "Database" exist and it has the function "RemoveCompletedRequests"

Comment: Thanks, Santosh.  Yes, found the function "RemoveCompletedRequests" ... here is the code stuff ...

Comment: have added RemoveCompletedRequests code stuff to query above so you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to reference the module that contains the macro. To be clear, remove `Database.` from `Database.RemoveCompletedRequests`. If you insist on doing so, you should avoid naming modules that could be confused with Objects. That is, you might want to call your module `modDatabase` instead.

Some other pointers: 
All variables should be declared/Dim'd at the start of the module. In `RemoveCompletedRequests`, for example, you're re-declaring your variables each time you loop through your For/Next. Move these to the top of your sub.

Finally, when you write something like `Dim i, j As Integer`, i is being declared as a Variant, not an Integer. You need to be explicit about these declarations: `Dim i as Integer, j As Integer`.